# How can I recover maven dependency issues after changing my Intellij license user account to a new account?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I changed the Intellij license user account I have been using and all my maven dependencies are no longer visible to my spring boot project. I deleted the *repository* folder in C:\Users{My Username}.m2, executed *mvn dependency:tree* and run *mvn clean install*. This has recovered my maven dependencies downloaded online. However, the dependencies included as POM from other projects residing on my system are still not visible.

Comment: You need to do a `mvn clean install` in each of your other projects directories.

Comment: Delete the configuration of intellij `.idea` directory and import the project new... it's problem of IDEA and not of Maven...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install other projects so that they are in the local repository and visible to the current project.

Answer (score 0):

Even without IntelliJ, you can simply go to each of your other local project folders and do a:

```
mvn dependency:resolve
```

Using that [`resolve` mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html), that would be enough to download the dependencies of those projects back to your new `%USERPROFILE%\.m2` cache folder.